# How to check if elements of a timestamp list are in a series that contains timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas

Problem:

I want to check what entries of a list of pandas.Timestamps are in a pandas.Timestamp series of a dataframe.
The problem is, when I use the `in` operator to check if a value from a list is in the series, an empty list is returned, even though a particular values is in the series.

Code:

1. A list of timestamps:

```
dates_range = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01", end="2019-01-31")
type(dates_range[0]) # pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

2. A series that contains timestamps:

```
type(_2019["dates"]) # pandas.core.series.Series
type(_2019["dates"].iloc[0]) # pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

3. Compare the first value of `dates_range` and `_2019["dates"]`:

```
_2019["dates"].iloc[0] == dates_range[0] # True
```

4. Crux:

```
dates_range[0] in _2019["dates"] # False

def get_dates_that_exist(data, datetime_arr):
    return [date for date in datetime_arr if date in data["dates"]] # Returns []
```

Why is it so? How can I check what dates from dates_range list are in _2019["dates"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check [Using the in operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator):

> Using the Python in operator on a Series tests for membership in the index, not membership among the values.

So if want test if at least one `True` for compare by first value for boolean mask and add [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
(_2019["dates"] == dates_range[0]).any()
```

And for test all data in `range` if match at least one value use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
_2019["dates"].isin(dates_range).any()
```

> I would like to know WHICH values are there

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
matched = _2019.loc[_2019["dates"].isin(dates_range), 'dates']
```

If need all columns:

```
df1 = _2019[_2019["dates"].isin(dates_range)]
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and what if I want to check which concrete entries from dates_range are in _2019["dates"]. What you provided checks if there is at least one value in dates_range that is is _2019["dates"]. I would like to know WHICH values are there.